# How to make content in an expand slot of a data table in VuetifyJS searchable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, full-text-search, vuetify.js

I'm using the [VuetifyJS/VueJS data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-search) with an [expand slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-expand). How to make the content in the expand slot searchable? I tried wrap the content within `<td></td>` but that didn't work.

Here is a codepen example: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBemRK?&editors=101`
If you search for "find me" it always results in a `Your search for "find me" found no results.`

```
      <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
    item-key="name"
  >

<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>

     <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
  <v-card flat>
    <v-card-text><td>Peek-a-boo! Please find me too.</td></v-card-text>
  </v-card>
         </template> 

    <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
      Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
    </v-alert>
  </v-data-table>
```

Comment: I recon the default search filter will try to find the correct rows based on the fields you have in your `desserts` variable. Since the expanded text does not appear there, you cannot find it. I am guessing you may need to add your expand text to your `desserts` rows, or override `filter` or `custom-filter` as per https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I added a `text` value to `dessert` and updated the CodePen example. Still nothing in the search result. How to a the row by using a custom-filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a custom filter.

First, create a custom filter method:

```
methods: {
    customFilter(items, search) {
      return items.filter(dessert => JSON.stringify(dessert).toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
    }
}
```

then add `:custom-filter="customFilter"` to the `v-data-table`:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :custom-filter="customFilter"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
    item-key="name"
>
```

See this updated codepen:
https://codepen.io/WisdomSky/pen/PBNvYY

Comment: If I could, I would give you ten +1, because your answer was really helpful. Thanks for unlocking my problem!

Comment: I'm glad I am of help to you :)

Answer (score 4):

Since Vuetify version >= 2 you'll need to use the `custom-filter` prop which has a new pattern.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    customDataTableItemsFilter(value, search, items) {
      /*
      Filter for individual words in search string. Filters
      all object values rather than just the keys included
      in the data table headers.
       */
      const wordArray = search
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(' ')
        .filter(x => x)
      return wordArray.every(word =>
        JSON.stringify(Object.values(items))
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(word)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly!!!  +++++++